# Using gdb to watch esi register

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to instruct gdb to watch the esi register, or to break on the esi register whenever it's value changes? I have a homework assignment and I need to determine consecutive esi values in hex.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to instruct gdb to watch the esi register, or to break on the esi register whenever it's value changes?

No. You'll need to find some *other way* to solve your problem.

> I have a homework assignment and I need to determine consecutive esi values in hex

Something like:

```
(gdb) display/x $esi
(gdb) stepi
(gdb)                        # Press Enter to repeat
```

might work.